# RFID Transmission from far away

Tags: rfid

Is it possible to trigger a reader from a standard RFID Access Control System? More specifically the badge system commonly used in companies for allowing entry. As in passing an ID to it?  Assuming you have a valid ID you can send to it.

I'm aware there are multiple technologies involved in these type of systems but I'm referring to the more common case (having to place a non-active tag near a reader).

Comment: Assuming that you know this: https://electronics.howstuffworks.com/gadgets/high-tech-gadgets/rfid2.htm then it would seem trivial to send the signal to the reader with strong equipment. Is there a reason why you would want to do this?

Comment: I don't have an application for it. It was just a discussion I had with my tech-geeky coworkers about the subject and sparked my curiosity. I hope that is ok for this forum.

Comment: Here is an example Long-Range RFID Reader -- https://silentbreaksecurity.com/a-new-tastic-thief/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to trigger a reader from a standard RFID Access Control System?

Yes, RFID is just radio waves on a certain frequency. Nothing stops somebody to put a powerful transmitter on that frequency and trigger a lot of readers.

> More specifically the badge system commonly used in companies for allowing entry.

Not in this case. Badges usually (almost always, but there are exceptions) have to "talk" to the reader, because the NFC tag have encryption. So even if your powerful transmitter can trigger the reader from 50m away, your receiver will not be able to receive the response. You don't just scream your ID and enter. There's an encripted talk between the badge and the reader.

This case is like putting a wifi antenna on a Pringles can and being able to receive signals from a lot of networks, but not being able to connect to the faint signals: their transmitter are string enough to reach you, but your transmitter aren't strong enough to reach them.

Comment: Would you be able to say how short distanced this handshaking protocol usually is? I know passive tags get powered by the reader but in case the reader gets triggered by a transmitter/receiver device somewhat near it (Maybe 2m away) the other device could handshake with it?

Comment: It really depends on how sensitive your receiver is, and the amount of interference around. A very sensitive receiver can work on 2m.

Answer (score 0):

There is a company selling safety equipment using the concept of remote RFID.  Construction person wears an RFID vest and the backhoe has a "card reader" on it and when it beeps the driver knows there is a person behind him etc.  The way RFID works for the most part you just need more copper wire to get a reading from further away.  There are offensive security applications for this.